# How can I move separate edges towards each other at the same time?

Tags: transforms, constraints

I know I can move each edge separately pressing the <kbd>G</kbd> and then the <kbd>Y</kbd> keys but how can I move
the edges **toward each other at the same time**?

[image]

After the edge move it would look something like this.
[image: image after move]

Comment: so what is it supposed to give at the end?

Comment: @moonboots I added image showing an example.

Comment: oh ok so yes, as Frederik Steinmetz says, S Y should be the solution

Comment: Thanks, that confused me. Never would have guessed scale to do that type of edge move.

Comment: Yep, scaling 2 points moves them closer together or farther apart (depending on transform pivot). Also, another "less heard of" operation with regards to scale is that you can flip an object by scaling it by -1 on whatever axis you want to flip it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They seem to be aligned along the world x axis, so with the selection shown, hit <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and move the mouse. Pressing <kbd>0</kbd>  will make them form one line through their exact center, which should be the x-axis.

If they are not aligned to a world axis, switch the transform orientation to normal first, edges have normals, too, they are not as reliable as the ones of faces, but more often than not, they get the job done.

Comment: ..or you could create a Custom Orientation from, say, the Y of one of the edges in line with the desired translation.